# Checkout with gift card

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, gift-card

I am using gift card to buy products in my store, but after pressing "continue" occurs error "pleace specify payment method" [image]

Comment: Please add what version of magento you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System->Configuration->SALES->Payment Methods->Zero Subtotal Checkout
set Enabled->yes